# How to geo-target the US and a specific state in AdWords/Bing Ads

Tags: google-ads

I want to be able to geo-target the US at 10% of bid and specific state at 100% of bid.

At the campaign level, I set the bid modifier for United States to decrease by 90% and simply included the state and set no bid modifier.

My concern is that by decreasing the US by 90% I am also decreasing the state by that amount too.

Will including the state as a target with no bid modifier prevent the state from being reduced by 90%?

Comment: You got me. I do not deal with these things. However, as you describe it, it sounds like you will target your desired state less because you decreased US. Can you decrease the other 49 states instead?? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Does this page help? https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1722043?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You could make a separate adwords campaign that only targets the state that you want to target at 100%.